# Oracle: How to get the Tenor of each month in two date range

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, analytics

I am trying to get the tenor per month of each month (from the start_dt) to end date. I want to use this in oracle analytics cloud.

```
| ID  | Start_dt  |  End_dt   | Tenor 
| --- | --------- | --------- | -----
| 1   | 13-AUG-15 | 14-SEP-15 | 33
| 2   | 14-AUG-15 | 14-SEP-15 | 32
| 3   | 12-AUG-15 | 14-SEP-15 | 34
| 5   | 13-AUG-20 | 13-AUG-21 | 365
...
| 444 | 13-AUG-20 | 13-AUG-20 | 1
```

expected output for any given month picked. e.g.  for the month of August:

```
ID  Start_dt    End_dt      Tenor   
1   13-AUG-15   31-AUG-15   19
2   14-AUG-15   31-AUG-15   18
3   12-AUG-15   31-AUG-15   20
5   13-AUG-20   31-AUG-15   19
...
444 13-AUG-20   13-AUG-20   1
```

for the month of September:

```
ID  Start_dt    End_dt      Tenor   
1   1-sep-15    14-sep-15   14
2   1-sep-15    14-SEP-15   14
3   1-sep-15    14-SEP-15   14
5   1-sep-15    31-SEP-15   31
....
```

Comment: How is tenor being calculated in the expected output? how is ID 1 in the first expected output showing 19 with a different end date? Then ID 1 in the expected output for September showing 14, but with dates in September instead of August?

Comment: The tenor is (Start_dt - End_dt )+ 1. Now the problem is i am trying to get the Tenor of each month between the star_dt to end_dt for each ID.

Comment: You seem to want the number of days in August in any year. But for your row with ID 5 the from/to cover a whole year; so you have 19 days from August 2020 *and* 13 days from August 2021. So why is the result only 19, not 32? Or should you have two separate rows in the results, one for each year? What if it spans multiple years? (Presumably in the results the dates ID 5 are typos - none of those should be 2015?)

Comment: I want the number of days within a start_dt to the last day of the start_dt till the End_dt runs out for a particular ID. Example: ID 9, Start_dt 20/MAY/2019 End_dt 3/Aug/2019, now i want to see the Tenor of each month within this two dates within a year (12 month, 365)

Comment: So "tenor" doesn't mean anything (or is meaningful only for you, but others are out of your context), and you want to split each interval into multiple rows by month (where each row of the output is the intersection of full month and input interval). Right?

Comment: But that's not what you said before; your example has all the data for any August, but really you want the breakdown of every month - within a specific year, or for a year from some input date? How will you provide that year or start value?

Comment: Reply to asternt:  YES  and the Start_dt and end_date are given in a table (just like investment start_date and mature_date). The reason i need the tenor is to calculate the interest per month for each month between  the start_dt to end_dt. So if i have the tenor i can be able to do that. And i was to use the information to create a report

Comment: After going through the solution link, it worked for a while then i get this error:      ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
01839. 00000 -  "date not valid for month specified"
*Cause:    
*Action: